# Mongoose Populate base on another field Dynamic ref

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I have two schema Teacher ,

```
const TeacherSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name:String
    _id: ObjectId
})
```

Student

```
const StudentSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name:String
    _id: ObjectId
})
```

and I have Comment schema

```
const CommentSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    description: String,
    user_type:String  // Student or Teacher
    user_id: ObjectId
})
```

how can I populate `CommentSchema` on based of `user_type` ,Eg. `if user_type === Teacher` user_id isfrom `TeacherSchema`

Answer (score 4):

In this case, you can use populate with [dynamic ref](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#dynamic-ref). For example:

```
const CommentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  description: String,
  user_type: String  // Student or Teacher
  user_id: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    refPath: 'user_type'
  }
})
```